# Where can I find sample Silverlight projects to learn with

Tags: silverlight

I'm in the process of learning Silverlight in the browser, and would like to get a finished application to poke around in. Something similar to how ASP.NET MVC has the Nerd Dinner web site source code available for download.

I'm not really sure how to search for this. "Silverlight Templates" is a good start, but I don't wan't just a UI template, i'm looking for a complete UI/Code application, preferably one that follows the MVVM paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.silverlight.net/learn, helped me a lot when learning silverlight.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I haven't been to that web site yet. Looks like there is a lot of helpful information there.